# Removing rows from a table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I need to remove some rows, each of which is associated with a checkbox from a table. I have come up with this so far:

```
$("#RemoveSelectedTests").click(function () {
    var testElements = [], len, rowToRemove;
    testElements = getSelectedTests('what', "selectedTests");
    len = testElements.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        rowToRemove = testElements[i].substring(testElements[i].lastIndexOf("(") + 1, testElements[i].lastIndexOf(")"));
        $("#" + rowToRemove).remove();
    }
});
```

To me the above seems correct, but the it seems to work a bit inconsistently. By this I mean, sometimes, it removes the rows correctly, other times, Remove button needs to be pressed more than once to get the rows to be removed. I am not sure what else is going on here. What might I be doing wrong?

`getSelectedTests` just gets the rows to process.

```
function getSelectedTests(what, id) {
    var selectedTests = [];
    $("#" + id + " .rdbtn[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function () {
        if (!what) {
            selectedTests.push($(this).val());
        }
        else {
            selectedTests.push($(this).data('desc') + ' (' + $(this).val() + ')');
        }
    });
    return selectedTests;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could do this a little simpler.

```
$(function () {
    $("#removeSelectedTests").click(function () {
        $(".rdbtn[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
            $(this).parents("tr").remove();
        });
    });
});

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="rdbtn" value=1></td>
    <td>Test 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="rdbtn" value=2></td>
    <td>Test 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="rdbtn" value=3></td>
    <td>Test 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="rdbtn" value=4></td>
    <td>Test 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="rdbtn" value=5></td>
    <td>Test 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="removeSelectedTests">Remove Tests</button>
```